# Magento Order Grid - Remote IP not showing

Tags: magento, grid

I'm trying to customize the admin order grid to display the remote ip of the order.

I followed the documentation to override the order grid block like shown in other topics here. The remote ip column appears in the page but no values are returned. I checked in the database to confirm the IP is present and I checked the query sent by the collection, everything seems in order.

Here is the block code :

```html
<?php

class Gawebstudio_Veloactif_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
 $this->addColumnAfter('remote_ip', array(
            'header'=> 'IP',
            'width' => '40px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'remote_ip',
        ), 'status');
  
 parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
 $collection->join('sales/order', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('remote_ip'));
 $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What's the result of an `echo $collection->getSelect();` ?

Comment: SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales/order`.`remote_ip` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `sales/order` ON sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id

Comment: I try to run this query in phpmyadmin  but had to replace"sales_flat_order" by "sales/order" since the query is not processed by Magento. 
It did return the correct IP for each order.

Comment: If you change : `$collection->join('sales/order', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('remote_ip'));` to `$collection->join('sales_order', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('remote_ip'));` ; Can you run the SQL query generated by Magento directly in PHPMyAdmin ?

-----

Because MySQL return : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/order ON sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id`

Comment: This query is first rewritten by Magento. Magento automatically checks the module called and changes the table name to the correct one. sales/order actually refers to sales_order_flat. Moreover, the orders appear correctly in my admin with the correct values and with the new IP column. The problem is that this column is empty. When I run the query in phpmyadmin, I get the correct IP, so Magento fails somewhere after running the query.

Comment: The new IP colmun appaers because it add in _prepareColumns() function

Comment: `$collection->join('sales/order', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('remote_ip'));` ==> `$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_grid', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id', array('remote_ip'));` OR  `$collection->join('sales_flat_order_grid', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id', array('remote_ip'));`?

Comment: Second one triggers an error :
Impossible de retrouver la configuration de l'entitÃ© : sales/sales_flat_order_grid

First one has no error but IP column still empty.
How does the overwrite system works in Magento if several modules try to overwrite the same grid ? The website has several module, none of them should touch this order grid but that might be a track ?

Comment: If you use `addColumn` instead of `addColumnAfter`, have you same result ?